# local storage on proxmox cluster, how to make it really local?

Tags: storage, proxmox

I am playing a bit around with proxmox cluster.
I have 2 servers. One of them, lets call it Virt01, has an extra disk, for storage.
I created a new extra local storage withis thuis disk, but proxmox associates that with both servers on the cluster.
Of course the large disk is only seen on the Virt01. Virt02 also gets the same path and storage but it's only a folder inside the already existing partition.

Is there a way to hide this? I only want the large disk to be avaialable to one of the servers.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to say in which nodes the storage is avaialble. For local storage (not shared) one only needs to select the local node where torage is situated.

Its's actually very simple but I missed the field the sfirst time.